# How to return preceding row value with column condition in SQL table?

Tags: sql, case, impala

I have the below SQL table in which I need the most recent price only when condition type is 00:

```
ProductID ConditionType Date        Price
00001          01        2018-01-01  4.00 
00001          01        2018-01-08  5.00   
00001          00        2018-01-09  4.50  
00001          01        2018-01-22  6.00  
00001          00        2018-01-29  3.00
```

I have tried using a lag function but am having trouble with the partitions.

```
select 
ProductID,ConditionType,Date,Price
,
case when conditiontype = 0 then
lag(Price,1) over (partition by ProductID,ConditionType order by Date asc)
else Price 
end as lag
from TABLE
```

Output from query:

```
ProductID ConditionType Date        Price  Lag
00001          01        2018-01-01  4.00  4.00
00001          01        2018-01-08  5.00  5.00 
00001          00        2018-01-09  4.50  null
00001          01        2018-01-22  6.00  6.00
00001          00        2018-01-29  3.00  4.50
```

Ideally we want to pull back the last price where condition type is 01 but I am having trouble getting this working.

Desired output:

```
ProductID ConditionType Date        Price  Lag
00001          01        2018-01-01  4.00  4.00
00001          01        2018-01-08  5.00  5.00 
00001          00        2018-01-09  4.50  5.00
00001          01        2018-01-22  6.00  6.00
00001          00        2018-01-29  3.00  6.00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `first_value()` and ignoring `NULL` values:

```
select t.*,
       first_value(case when conditionType = '00' then price end ignore nulls) over
           (partition by productId
            order by date desc
           ) as most_recent_00_price
from t;
```

EDIT:

I misunderstood the question.  I thought you wanted the most recent in the data.  You want the "running" most recent value.

The simplest way in SQL uses `lag(ignore nulls)`, but that is not supported by Impala.  But you can use two window functions:

```
select t.*,
       max(case when date = date_00 then price end) over (partition by productId) as most_recent_00_price
from (select t.*,
             max(case when conditionType = '00' then date end) over (partition by productId order by date) as date_00
      from t
     ) t
```

Comment: what happens if case ='00' does not happen what value will be printed?

Comment: @nikhilsugandh . . . `NULL`.

Comment: From what I have tested this does not bring back the desired result, only the first conditiontype ='00' price.

Comment: @QuestionAsker . . . I misunderstood the question and have revised the answer.

Comment: Thank you @GordonLinoff I got it working using your edit.

Answer (score 1):

You only need one partition clause in `lag()` :

```
select ProductID, ConditionType, Date, Price,
       (case when conditiontype = '00' 
             then lag(Price) over (partition by ProductID order by Date)
             else Price 
        end) as Lag
from TABLE;
```

Comment: I attempted this query and when there are two condition type = '00' entries in a row, the query returns the previous condition type ='00' price and not the previous 01 price.